# Integrate a whole Yeoman, AngularJS project using one single file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I am currently creating a form, using Yeoman and AngularJS (1.2.27).

This form aims to be integrated in any of my clients web pages. So I can generate a dist folder with grunt, that contains a lot of files, such as JS files, CSS files, Images, Fonts, Components etc.

But what I would like, is to be able to give a single Javascript file that anyone can include to his website, and maybe a tag or something integrated by the client to his website as well. Then, this file will build the entire Angular application (which will be stored on my server) inside that tag.

Do you have any idea if such thing is possible, and if yes do you have some hints to give me?

Thanks guys

Comment: Wait, you want JS files, CSS files, Images, Fonts, Components etc. all combined to 1 file?

Comment: Not really, I'd like to know if it is possible to have one single JS file making a call to my server, getting my app, and generating the app on a client website.

Comment: Well, you can combine all of your JS files in 1 file and send back that one. But, what about all the HTML files ?

Comment: I got only one html file, index.html. My app already send request on each route in order to get the corresponding html file, that is stored on my backend server

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

1. List down all your framework related files.
2. List down all your JS files. This includes your routers, controllers, services, etc.

You can combine and minify the above files to generate 1 single JS file, something like 'application.js'. This file will take care of your entire app.

Now, since your index.html file is already there, include this 'application.js' file in your index file.

Comment if this is what you want to do.

Comment: And what can I do with these folders : styles, images, fonts, bower_components, that are generated by `grunt build` as well

Comment: For your css, you can use the same approach of combine and min. For others, I'm afraid you will have to use it as it is. Maybe there's a better approach. I have done this only for my JS and CSS files. Keep looking.